# Ensamblador duda lenguaje maquina

Tags: ensamblador

No entiendo de donde saca la traducción a lenguaje maquina en esta línea que marco.
Entiendo todo sin problemas pero esa traducción que hace no la veo y mire por muchos sitios.

¿De donde sale el EBFF de los bytes 3 y 3 de esa linea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

FFEB claramente es un desplazamiento, y se debería interpretar como -21.

Suponiendo que el contador de programa apunte a la siguiente instrucción (lo que suelen hacer casi todas las arquitecturas, excepto algunas como ARM), al ejecutar JL el contador de programa apuntaría a 0003fc1c, y suponiendo que se tome el salto:

0003fc1c-21 = 0003fc07

Se saltaría a la segunda instrucción de la tabla.